# Apache Camel authentication with a token

Tags: authentication, apache-camel, token

I have an old endpoint under Apache Camel 2.20.1 and it used basic authentication.
Example: imaps://Outlook.office365.com:993?mail.smtp.auth=true&mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true&password=xxxxxx&username=test%40test.com
Microsoft will add second authentication by the token. What options can I test to process authentication successfully as usual and can read emails using the token provides by outlook.

Thanks.